# What happens if I `sendrawtransaction` but tx is invalid?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, doublespend, utxo, sendrawtransaction

I manually select from my UTXOs, sign the tx (offline programmatical signing, not with wallet) and only interact with bitcoind when I call `sendrawtransaction`. But in the meantime another process might have chosen one of the same UTXOs and have already been broadcast before mine.

At which point would I realize my tx broadcast didn't make it? Would `sendrawtransaction` return error? Or would it be only evident if I call `gettransaction` with the txid returned by `sendrawtransaction`? It would say "no such tx exists"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendrawtransaction` submits your transaction to your own node's mempool for validation and relay. If it is not accepted, an error will be returned which will be returned to the user by the RPC.

Comment: So that means that, given the other competing transaction that snatched one of my UTXOs is also submitted to the same node, my own node will return error to the `sendrawtransaction` call?

Comment: If your node has accepted the other transaction to its own mempool, then yes, it will give you an error when you use `sendrawtransaction`.